# checkbox value is inserted blank?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i have a programme in which i want to insert checkbox value & image field which is generated dynamically according to checkbox value.all checkbox name & all images name is same. all other data is inserted successfully but checkbox value not inserted. please help me. my php code is :

```
<?php
include_once('connection.php');
$msg='';
$prod_imgs='';
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
    $category_id=$_REQUEST['category']; 
    $product_id=$_REQUEST['product'];
    $relation_id=$_REQUEST['relation'];
    $occasion_id=$_REQUEST['occasion'];
    $prod_image = $_FILES['prod_image']['name'];
    $tmp_prod_image=$_FILES['prod_image']['tmp_name'];
    for($i=0;$i<count($prod_image);$i++)
    {

        if($prod_image[$i]!='')
        {
            $image="product_images/".$prod_image[$i];
            //$occasion=$occasion_id[$i];
            $insert=mysql_query("insert into tbl_add_product_occasion  values('','$category_id','$product_id','$relation_id','$occasion_id','$image')");
        if($insert)
        {
            $msg="your product info added successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            $msg="an error occur";
        }
    }
    }
echo $msg;
}
?>
```

& the html code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_product(cat){      
                                  // alert(cat);
                                   $.ajax({
                                      type : "POST",
                                      url : 'ajax_get_product.php',
                                      data : 'cat=' +cat,
                                      success : function(data){
                                        //alert(data);
                                        document.getElementById('prod').innerHTML=data;
                                            //society_code').innerH''TML=data.d;
                                         }
                                      });

        };


</script>
<form action="" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <fieldset>
                 <dl>
                        <dt><label for="gender">Select category:</label></dt>
                        <dd>
                            <select  name="category" id="category" onchange="get_product(this.value)" >
                                <option>select category</option>
                                <?php
                                $sel=mysql_query("select * from tbl_category");
                                while($arr=mysql_fetch_array($sel))
                                {
                                    $id=$arr['id'];
                                    echo "<option value='".$id."'>".$arr['category']."</option>";
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                    <dl>
                    <dt><label for="product">Select Product:</label></dt>
                        <dd>
                            <select name="product" id="prod">
                                <option value=''>select product</option>

                            </select>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>

                    <dl>
                    <dt><label for="option">choose relation:</label></dt>
                    <dd>
                    <select name="relation">
                    <?php
                    $query=mysql_query("select * from tbl_relation");
                    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query))
                    {
                        $relation=$result['relation'];
                        $relation_id=$result['id'];
                        echo "<option value='".$relation_id."'>".$relation."</option>";         

                    }?>
                    s</select>
                    </dd>
                    </dl>
                    <dl>
                    <dt><label for="option">choose Occasion:</label></dt>
                    <div style="float:left;width: 400px;margin-top: 9px;">
                    <?php
                        $select=mysql_query('select * from tbl_occasion');
                        while($array=mysql_fetch_array($select))
                        {
                            $occasion_id=$array['id'];
?>


<dd style="width:auto;">
<span id="" style="width:115px; float:left;"><input type="checkbox" name="occasion[]" value="<?php echo $occasion_id;?>" /><?php echo $array['occasion'];?></span>
<input type="file" name="prod_image[]"/>

</dd>

<?php
}
?>
                    </div>
                    </dl>
                    <dl class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Enter" />
                     </dl>
                </fieldset>

             </form>
```

please help me to solve this problem.
thanks in advance..

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: `document.getElementById('prod').innerHTML += data;` or `$('#prod').html(data);`

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
<?php
include_once('connection.php');
$msg='';
$prod_imgs='';
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
    $category_id=$_REQUEST['category']; 
    $product_id=$_REQUEST['product'];
    $relation_id=$_REQUEST['relation'];
    $occasion=$_REQUEST['occasion'];
    $prod_image = $_FILES['prod_image']['name'];
    $tmp_prod_image=$_FILES['prod_image']['tmp_name'];
    for($i=0;$i<count($prod_image);$i++)
    {

        if($prod_image[$i]!='')
        {
            $image="product_images/".$prod_image[$i];
            $occasion_id=$occasion[$i];
            $insert=mysql_query("insert into tbl_add_product_occasion  values('','$category_id','$product_id','$relation_id','$occasion_id','$image')");
            if($insert)
            {
              $msg="your product info added successfully";
            }
            else
            {
               $msg="an error occur";
            }
         }
      }
      echo $msg;
}
?>
```

Comment: check using print_r($occasion);

Comment: yap it's giving the value using print_r($occasion), but not inserted in database.

Comment: echo $occasion_id=$occasion[$i]; this line

Comment: please show the output of print_r($occasion); also does it go to for loop